# Is the following set a polyhedron?

Tags: polyhedra

Is the following set a polyhedron, where $a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$?
\begin{align}
U = \{ X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}: a^T_1Xa_1 \leq a^T_2 X a_2 \}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by *a polyhedron*. $U$ is a linear halfspace orthogonal to the vector whose $i, j$-th coordinate is $v_{ij} = (a_1)_i (a_1)_j - (a_2)_i (a_2)_j.$

Comment: The usual definition for polyhedron in combinatorial optimization is: a polyhedron is the intersection of finitely many halfspaces of the form $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \leq b \}$

Comment: @AlexGuevara Wel, $1$ is finitely many...

Comment: are there any other common definitions of polyhedron which may change the fact whether the expression is one or not?

Comment: I also do not directly see why from the orthogonality property the $Ax \leq b$ condition follows

Comment: @AlexGuevara polyhedra are sometimes assumed to be compact. As for the last comment, think about it.